# Pulling bank information: Alternatives to Yodlee API?

Tags: api, scraping

[Yodlee](http://www.yodlee.com/) has an Instant Account Verification API that allows a user to login into their bank account, answer security questions and return back a list of accounts + transactions.

We need a similar API that could allow us to pull more details about the account, specifically the routing number (US) and transit number (CAD).

Yodlee does not provide the transit number so we're looking for alternatives.

Is there anything out there that allows similar functionality?

Comment: Perhaps OFX can do this.